# How to create Iterable in Win32 app from e.g. std::vector

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop-bridge

I am using Win32 with Windows App SDK for listing all in-app purchase products from Windows Store. But I don´t know how to create `ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collection::Iterable<HSTRING>` instance.

[image]

Comment: use C++/WinRT "Collections with C++/WinRT" : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/collections

Comment: @SimonMourier I can' t use  Windows::Foundation::Collections. I have to use ABI:: Windows::Foundation::Collections and syntax  ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<int> coll{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<int>() }; not allowed

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an interface. You can create instances of classes that implement a certain interface. I'm not familiar with the WRL, though I *think* you can use the [`Implements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/implements-structure) class template for the type you'll be authoring (that contains your collection of choice and implements the required interfaces over it). Writing that code is **extremely** challenging. Since you're passing the interface into an `Async` function the object needs to be agile. A single-threaded implementation won't do.

Comment: Not found the proper collections. It's needed to create a class which implements `ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collection::Iterable`.